# Port open, but not forwarding

Tags: wireless-networking, ports

I have a Buffalo WZR-1800h, and I opened port 25565 on it and forwarded it to an active server which I can connect locally to. We just got a new router and the server ran flawlessly on the other router. An online port checker says the port is open. So basically it is not forwarding the ports, just opening them. I have both UDP and TCP enabled.

Comment: How did you establish that it wasn't forwarding the ports?

Answer (score 1):

If the port is shown as "open" it is forwarding traffic. The reason it shows "open" is most likely because the testing software was able to initiate a TCP session using the port. However, there are many things that can prohibit proper bidirectional traffic flow. Make sure the IP addresses are correct, ports are correct, and that the server is not responding in the way it should.

Comment: +1. a port is opened by an application. if the router forwards to a server port that does not have a service running on it, it appears closed, because it is. there's usually no way to observe that a path to a server port goes through a nat filter in either direction, so the port checker could not detect a state where you were forwarding but the app was offline. it would appear closed either way.

Comment: Hence, "and that the server is not responding in the way it should" :)